# Skip cart page for a few products redirecting to checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I would like to bypass cart page and redirect user to checkout page for a few products.

I have created the add to cart link for the product 
`<a href="http://example.net/?add-to-cart=1461">Product Name</a>`

And I have the code below

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'woo_redirect_checkout' );

function woo_redirect_checkout() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $desire_product = 1461;
    //Get product ID
    $product_id = (int) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_POST['add-to-cart'] );

    //Check if current product is subscription
    if ( $product_id == $desire_product ){
        $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
        return $checkout_url;
        exit;
    } else {
        $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();
        return $cart_url;
        exit;
    }
}
```

from [How to skip cart page on woocomerce for certain products only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962653/how-to-skip-cart-page-on-woocomerce-for-certain-products-only). But the url redirect me to homepage instead. Just wondering where is the issue,

I have unchecked the add to cart behaviour at woocommerce settings as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I chose another approach and a WordPress hook instead of woocommerce. This is based on this answer: [WooCommerce - Skip cart page redirecting to checkout page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655722/woocommerce-skip-cart-page-redirecting-to-checkout-page/39656479#39656479)

This is that code:

```
 function skip_cart_page_redirection_to_checkout() {

    // desired product id redirection
    $product_id = 1461;
    $items_ids = array();

    // Get all items IDs that are in cart
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        $items_ids[] = $item['product_id'];
    }

    // If is cart page and the desired peoduct is in cart => redirect to checkout.
    if( is_cart() && in_array($product_id, $items_ids) )
        // WooCommerce 3.0 compatibility added
        if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '2.7', '<' ) ) {
            wp_redirect( WC()->cart->get_checkout_url() ); // Older than 3.0
        } else {
            wp_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url() ); // 3.0+ (Thanks to helgatheviking)
        }

}
add_action('template_redirect', 'skip_cart_page_redirection_to_checkout');
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

The code is tested and fully functional.

Comment: Source comment says that `get_checkout_url()` is deprecated, but it isn't *actually* deprecated. Anyway, [source](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L636-L645) advises using `wc_get_checkout_url()`.

Comment: @helgatheviking Oh thanks, updated for all versions… I know, a lot of my answers are now not compatible with woocommerce 3.0+ … I will try to update them progressively…

Comment: Source says that `wc_get_checkout_url()` was available since 2.5. :shrugs: :) That doesn't negate what you said about answers now being outdated. I wouldn't worry about it much though. They were right when you posted.