# Skip WooCommerce cart for specific subscription products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I wish to make multiple specific subscription products skip the cart and go straight to checkout. I found the following code here (only for one product), which skips it for one product using the product ID, but unable to adapt it for multiple products. Tried also various other methods, but none seem to work for Woocommerce 4.51

[How to skip cart page on woocomerce for certain products only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962653/how-to-skip-cart-page-on-woocomerce-for-certain-products-only)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'woo_redirect_checkout' );

function woo_redirect_checkout() {

   global $woocommerce;

   $desire_product = '73458';

   //Get product ID

   $product_id = (int) apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', $_POST['add-to-cart'] );

   //Check if current product is subscription

   if ( $product_id == $desire_product ){

       $checkout_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();

       return $checkout_url;

       exit;

   } else {

       $cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();

       return $cart_url;

       exit;

   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect` filter gives you access to the product object of the product that was added to the cart. So you can check for the subscription product type:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'woo_redirect_checkout', 10, 2 );
function woo_redirect_checkout( $url, $product ) {
    return $product->get_type() == 'subscription' ? wc_get_checkout_url() : $url;
}
```

Now all products that are of type `subscription` get redirected to the checkout instead of the cart.

If you do not want all your subscription products to redirect to the checkout but only subscriptions in certain categories, you can first retrieve the product categories from the product object and see if they match one of the categories defined in the `$checkout_cats` array:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'woo_redirect_checkout', 10, 2 );
function woo_redirect_checkout( $url, $product ) {

    //Define your categories here
    $checkout_cats = array( 'Music', 'Posters' );

    if ( $product->get_type() == 'subscription' ) {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );
        if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                if ( in_array( $term->name, $checkout_cats ) ) return wc_get_checkout_url();
            }
        }
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: ok thank you and how would I do it if I only wish to do it for multiple specific subscription products, instead of all? Could define them based on category or also individual product ID/slug

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted, and possibly vote it up.

Comment: I would like to, but it doesnt work:
'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_type() on null in wp-content/themes/oceanwp-child/functions.php:331'

Comment: This means the `$product` variable does not contain a product object. How are you adding the product to your cart and is it an actual product?

Comment: definitelty a product, just looked at the WC documentation, it says the following:

A subscription product is a custom product type that can be selected when creating a new product. When referring to a subscription product in the WooCommerce Subscriptions code base, $product or $product_id will be used as the variable name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222001/discussion-between-khufu-and-terminator-barbapapa).